movie about a rodeo cowboy and a mechanic girl (raped by her redneck brother)
I usually can find all the movies I look for with the information I have, but this one is eluding me.
I thought the girls was Daryl Hannah, but by her filmography it appears I was wrong.
the movie revolves around 2 characters, at the beginning there's this rodeo cowboy who takes part in various tournaments in which he rides wild horses and tries to set a new time record. he always carries his own saddle.
then we see this girl fixing a car, and her redneck brother who rapes her (the movie makes you understand that this goes on since she was little).
I don't remember if the cowboy meet her and kills her brother, or if she does. I think she kills him and then flees, and then she meets the cowboy though.
I don't remember much else, I think they need to stay away from the police because they killed the brother and the cowboy only need to win another tournament. he does and set a new record.
he says before that he wants to retire and buy a ranch in Canada (or he inherited it from some relative, I'm not sure), so the plan is that they will cross the border illegally and go to the ranch.
the police catch up with them and he gets shot, he tells the girl to go alone and save herself and he stays behind lying in the snow while the police is chasing them.
it might be a tv-movie, or I don't know... I think they main characters might be famous actors, but I'm not sure at this point!

Sounds like FTW (AKA Last Ride) with Mickey Rourke from 1994. He plays a rodeo cowboy and Lori Singer (that does resemble Daryl Hannah) plays a young mechanic who's sexually abused by her brother (Peter Berg). The brother dies (but he's shot by the cops) and Rourke helps her escape the authorities. Here's a clip.

In fact, she resembles her so much that some have wondered if they're the same person :) https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110606124556AAuyR8v

that's it! thank you so much!
edit: you are right, I was so sure she was Daryl Hannah that I must have searched through her filmography at least 4 times before giving up and asking her for help :)
